# Non-periodic continued fraction with explicitly known convergents?

Tags: irrational-numbers, continued-fractions, golden-ratio

Is an irrational number with non-periodic continued fraction expansion known, for which one can give explicit formulas for the convergents $p_n/q_n$ or at least for the denominators $q_n$ (similar to the convergents $F_{n+2}/F_{n+1}$ of the golden ratio, where $F_n$ is the n-th Fibonacci number)?

Comment: Some good information about the continued fraction convergents for $e$ and related numbers can be found [at this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/eContinuedFraction.html).

Comment: $e$ is even transcendental and has a clear pattern in the simple continued fraction that continues forever. This implies that there are formulas for the convergents of $e$.